# How do I query a backend layout which is set by parent page?

Tags: layout, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

Currently I am using the following conditional TypoScript to check which backend layout is set:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page|backend_layout = 2]
  // some typoscript
[global]
```

In addition I have a site tree structure like this:

```
- rootPage1
    - page1
    - page2
    - page3
- rootPage2
    - page1
    - page2
```

Now I want to use a different backend layout for **rootPage2** and all childs of this page. So I have configured this page as follows:

[image]

This works as expected and set a different backend layout for rootPage2 and all his childs, but the conditional statement is not working for his childs. Only if I set the backend layout for all this childs manually it is working :(.

Do I need a different conditional statement for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use different condition, specifically write your own [userFunc condition](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-userfunc)

Put this code into your `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` (exactly in this place, create file if necessary):

```
function user_beLayout($layout) {

    if (TYPO3_MODE!='FE') return false;

    if($GLOBALS["TSFE"]->page["backend_layout"] > 0)
        return $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->page["backend_layout"] == $layout;

    foreach ($GLOBALS["TSFE"]->rootLine as $page)
        if($page["backend_layout_next_level"] > 0) 
            return ($page["backend_layout_next_level"] == $layout);

    return false;
}
```

So you can use it in your TS like:

```
[userFunc = user_beLayout(2)]
 // some typoscript
[end]
```

And here's the link to [gist with comments](https://gist.github.com/biesior/0d6b26671015d50f417c#file-additionalconfiguration-php)