# typoscript backend_layout_next_level not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have the following config

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        templateRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Website/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Website/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Website/Layout/
        file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        file.stdWrap.cObject {
            key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
            key.override.field = backend_layout

            default = TEXT
            default.value = whatever.html

            1 < .default

            2 = TEXT
            2.value = whatever-else.html
    }
}
```

Somehow the 'backend_layout_next_level' is not working; it is not sliding down the tree. As a result I have to set a backend_layout for each page which is not what one should expect.

Is there a way of knowing/debugging/finding out what's causing this? I thought it might be something related to a curly brace being in the wrong place (too early, too late or just plain wrong) inside my typoscript. Therefor I looked inside the Typoscript Template Analyzer and found some errors which I've fixed, but the problem still persists.

Thanks already!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

TBH I never understood this *@^$#%* `CASE` syntax... Therefore definitely prefer common condition which works perfect, you must to add custom condition like [I showed in other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33302318/1066240), so you can use it like:

```typoscript
page {
    typeNum = 0
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        templateRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Website/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Website/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Website/Layout/
        file = whatever.html
    }
}

[userFunc = user_beLayout(2)]
    page.10.file = whatever-else.html
[userFunc = user_beLayout(3)]
    page.10.file = yet-other.html
[userFunc = user_beLayout(4)]
    page.10.file = etc.html
[end]
```

#### Edit - to satisfy some comments

*Note: When I say that I don't understand `CASE` syntax, that doesn't mean that I don't know it... especially that I studied it in details not once, here's the conclusion...*

**About performance:**

Custom conditions solution is *faster* than using `CASE` and `slide` combination as it doesn't involve additional DB queries (`slide` does), it iterates `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->page` array, which is already collected, and stops further checks ASAP, so it's cheaper than `slide` which makes additional queries if it finds `slide` in TS (doesn't matter if it's required or not) - ([examine the code for `slide` mechanics](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_6-2/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentContentObject.php#L66)), so actually conditions are *performance-saver* not *killer* :)

**Yet more**

Using conditions blocks you can change behavior of *multiple* elements at once (instead writing separate CASE for each) i.e.:

```
[userFunc = user_beLayout(2)]
    page.10.file = whatever-else.html
    lib.genericMenu >
    config.absRefPrefix = /layout-specific-abs/
    // etc...
[end]
```

Using `CASE` syntax you'll need to repeat all these checks for each element... (where's DRY?)

**Finally**

Both solutions are ... usable especially when using with cached pages, (difference between them will be about teens or maybe in drastic situation hundred milliseconds -conditions will be faster), for uncached pages most probably it will be good idea to set `be_layout` directly for each `pages` record in both cases.

Comment: This is properly the worst way to implement this!

Comment: @pgampe I'm curious about your opinion (note that I have really problems with CASE syntax)

Comment: 1. Your solution is a performance killer. 2. The ``CASE`` object is very simple. It looks at the value of the ``key`` (after ``stdWrap``) and then searches a property named like this value. This propery is then evaluated as ``cObject``. Otherwise the propery ``default`` is evaluated as ``cObject``. The result from either the property named after the value in ``key`` or  from ``default`` is returned as result of ``CASE``.

Comment: @pgampe, generally you're wrong, check my edit and especially examine the referenced slide mechanics code. Next time be just more careful about thesis you are proclaim

Comment: Your solution need to be evaluted on **EVERY** page call, independent of whether the page is cached or not. Using ``CASE`` the condition is only evaluated once during the template generation and the result is cached with the rest of the template for further calls. Every global condition is evaluated on every page call!

Comment: In your example you have three additional global condition matching evaluations (with lots of code). Btw, you can reuse the evaluation of ``CASE`` objects by storing the value in a register.

Comment: _Your solution need to be evaluted on EVERY page call_ : therefore I finalize it ASAP, it's still cheaper than adding next DB queries to several hundreds that T3 made before

Comment: But those DB calls only happen on page generation, yours happen on every page call, even on fully cached pages, because global conditions are evaluated every time, independent of caching. And there is another problem: Cache invalidation. You need to explicitly clear the fronted cache for pages down the root level, because otherwise TYPO3 just stores another variant of the page in cache.

Comment: Note: If you are just worried about the ``slide`` performance, you can use your user function for the ``.key`` property of ``CASE``.

Answer (score 0):

You use have to give the full path to the file as a value in the `.file` property or you should use `.templateName` instead and only provide the name (case sensitive!!!) of the template file without suffix.

@see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

Note that in your current setting, the `uid` of the template record must be `1` or `2`.

And you can try to use `levelfield: -2` instead of `levelfield: -1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite some time ago, you probably resolved your issue but here is a working approach:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        # select different html files for layouts - ref: backend_layout
        file.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
        file.stdWrap.cObject {
            data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
            override.field = backend_layout
            split {
                token = pagets__
                1.current = 1
                1.wrap = |
            }
            wrap = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Templates/|.html
        }
        layoutRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        partialRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
}
```

or you can pass it as a variable:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Templates/Main.html
        layoutRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        partialRootPath = EXT:folder/Resources/Private/Partials/
        variables {

        # BE_Layout
        BE_Layout = COA
        BE_Layout {
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject {
                data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
                override.field = backend_layout
                split {
                    token = pagets__
                    1.current = 1
                    1.wrap = |
                }
                wrap = |.html
            }
        }
    }
}
```