# Hide specific elements on page (Typoscript)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, element

Is there some way how to hide specific elements on specific page using Typoscript in TYPO3?

The URL is for example: www.mywebsite.com/subpage1

I want to hide menu and footer part only on this subpage1.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the menu and footer are created through TypoScript you can use conditions in TypoScript to overwrite them. For example:

```
lib.footer = TEXT
lib.footer.value = This is my footer

[globalVar = TSFE:id = 4]
lib.footer >
[global]
```

In this example the uid of the page where I want to not show the footer is 4.

More on conditions in TypoScript can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference.html

Comment: be aware that `TSFE:id` will be depricated, use `[page|uid = 4]` instead.

Comment: And if the menu and footer are not created through TypoScript?

Comment: Then how are they created?

Comment: They are created using TemplaVoila. This TYPO3 is old and I do not know how to use TemplaVoila, that´s why I am asking if there is another solution.

Comment: Menu's are usually created with TypoScript when using TemplaVoila. Footers could be static parts of the template, but can also be created with TypoScript (usually depends on what's in the footer). You can however also create a different template for that page that doesn't contain the menu and footer. It's a bit much to explain how here if you don't know TemplaVoila, but this should get you on your way: http://typo3buddy.com/typo3-template-tutorial/templavoila/

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial :)

Answer (score 3):

A clean way would be to define different page-layouts and assign them to the pages where these elements are not desired. With fluid partials you could recycle most parts of the page and depending on the layout render footer and menu.

As you get a nice inheritance mostly the fields `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level` are used. You will find a lot of examples.

fluid handling could be found in [typoscript backend_layout_next_level not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415138/typoscript-backend-layout-next-level-not-working).

---

For templa voila (=TV) you can use a similar attempt: select different TV-templates depending on these fields.
Duplicate the given template, remove footer and menu and insert the new template to the set of given templates.

Comment: And if this page uses TemplaVoila and not fluidtemplate?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)